# Why doesn't Typescript infer return values correctly when possible return object types are specifically defined?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to understand how Typescript infers the return values from a function call. Say I have a function called `sendRequest` that can return two specifically formatted objects. Why isn't Typescript able to know that if `loading` is `true`, that the only possible value for `data` is `null`, and that if `loading` is `false`, the only possible value for `data` is a `Data` type? It is still saying that `data` could be `null` even though that's impossible based on the possible return types listed.

```
type Data = { firstName: string; lastName: string };

type ReturnType =
  | { loading: true; data: null }
  | { loading: false; data: Data };

const sendRequest = (fetch: boolean): ReturnType => {
  if (fetch) {
    return { loading: true, data: null };
  }

  return { loading: false, data: { firstName: 'Bart', lastName: 'Simpson' } };
};

const { loading, data } = sendRequest(true);

if (loading) {
  data; // <-- Typescript says that `data` can be either `Data` or `null`, while based on the return type, and since `loading` if `true`, `data` can't be `null`.
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works as a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) until you destructure the variables. TypeScript can understand that the data type of the union is conditional on the value of `loading`, but it doesn't keep this information once you break it apart into two variables.

```js
const ret = sendRequest(true);

if (!ret.loading) {
  ret.data; // <-- This is now of type Data, not null.
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=2&pln=15&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOUC8UDeUBmBLATgZ2ADk4BbCALikN2wDsBzAbigBs5CTyqb6GoAvkwBQw0JCgAlCMACuuOgBVwEABophUKAB90bAPZwAJnyrBcsiCyMI4VOrNatBmnXtaGTjKpjit8VlA2iFTwiIIiwgDG+nSE1BB0RtIAjpbxqAAUmDJRABZUAEb6+qwQcHQAlFTScgrKkOrIAHzortiYUNm5eZVtWlq4MvJ07p6mUOaWADRBtvaOzkKuAqKDwwpjxhO+-hCzwXZ6OATEZJRQAOQAQnC4wJez7JznVJcAytikYPixl4IRYTLaKxeJDYAoBJJVLpYCZKYQSqRDpdACE4IAdB5tow+mhXJjDiwAPTEqAAHgAtJSoA0IPgorQwBD8HAQPhJnkEFAAAaHHlQKIVKCFaAQbDAPIQXC8sJwAX6GU8hxOHmzADueWwZRFHAgRigsU50HBI0mKlmFQN+HoUWgPOxXgYApRPIRat5-MFFUuENFvJVrB5GKBQA)

As [jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz) points out in the comments, the behavior you're requesting is tracked as [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581). (Thanks jcalz!)

Comment: See [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) for more about TypeScript's lack of support for keeping track of "correlated unions" like this.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing worth noting is that you don't want to use `ReturnType` as a custom type name since that actually has a reserved purpose as of TypeScript 2.8.

But to answer your question: The reason that TypeScript complains is because that's how you've specified the return type. When `loading` is `true`, `data` is `null`:

```
type Response =
  | { loading: true; data: null }
  | { loading: false; data: Data };
```

In fact, I'm surprised that TypeScript even types it as `Data | null` rather than `null` alone. That is indeed the case in TS Playground:

[image: a variable named data appears to be of type Data or null]